# OpenPGP keyserver URLs: what are typical or meaningful use-cases?

Tags: pgp

i'm getting re-acquainted with OpenPGP and noticed that GnuPG allows me to store a "preferred keyserver" URL in my keys:

```
reuben@localhost:~$ gpg2 --edit-key 'Reuben NP Garrett <my-special-email@example.com>'
gpg> help
..
keyserver   set the preferred keyserver URL for the selected user IDs
```

this seems to influence GPG's 'refresh-keys' operation, since when i tried setting this value to http://pgp.mit.edu/ (where i'd previously published my keys), GPG complained of "no key data found for http://pgp.mit.edu/". however, when the keyserver URL was set to an unreachable value (https://pgp.mit.edu/), GPG instead complained that it "couldn't connect to host" and failed over to keys.gnupg.net (as a built-in server, i suspect).

is the "preferred keyserver" URL supposed to directly target my key, e.g. http://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?op=vindex&search=0x0B17E17AADF01139? or what is a "correct" (or useful/meaningful) way to set this property?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### The Option

This option allows you to setup the preferred key server others *should* (but not must) use when refreshing your key. This could be your own, or the one your institution provides. A preferred key server can reduce the synchronization latency between OpenPGP participants.

#### Key Exchange Protocols

You must not enter the http URL of the key server. GnuPG uses another protocol for key exchange, namely hkp. For `pgp.mit.edu` use `hkp://pgp.mit.edu`.

There is a [post on security.pgp-basics describing all the available protocols](https://web.archive.org/web/20160727011459/https://osdir.com/ml/security.pgp-basics/2006-12/msg00027.html):

- ldap (might be important in some enterprise scenarios)
- hkp (*the* de-facto standard for all key server operations ourdays)
- http
- finger
- mailto (had broad usage in earlier days, especially for exchanging information between key servers)

#### SKS Key Server Pool

Even better, use the SKS key server pool MIT is participating in: `hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net`. Most key servers (but http://wwwkeys.pgp.net) are well-connected among each other and synchronize very fast, so selecting a distinct key server isn't very important. Using the SKS key server pool is usually recommended, as it contains all the relevant key servers and increases availability over using a dedicated key server.

Comment: i discovered the `hkp:` scheme shortly after posting, and it worked as expected. also, thank you for the info on the SKS pool - will start using it!

Comment: Unfortunately, the link to the post is no longer working. It would be great, if you could summarize the available protocols.

Comment: I found the post on archive.org, added some words anyway.

Comment: the SKS key server pool has been taken down (due to GPDR) and there is no plan to bring it back up.  I suggest php.mit.edu instead